# How to call big button's click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, uibutton

I am trying to build button designer(Changing the buttons place and group them)
Just like the iphone's app designer
When i make button group, the little button is on the big button
and big button is parent of little button.
Little button is child. Big button is parent.
And little button is over the big button
The problem is i want click just big button but also little button is there 
I dont want to click little button
But i want to see the visual of the small button

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rephrase this question!

"I want make little button clickablely transparent, But the visual of the little button(child button) should be visible"

Did you mean you want the big button to not be clickable, and for the little button to be pressed?

If that's the case, simply make the large button not intractable, and get rid of the collision for the big button. Then the little button will be intractable.